# Should I set a license in the constructor or a static constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor

We are using the Aspose PDF library to work with PDF files. Aspose requires the license to be set once per process. Accordingly, I have created the following common static method that sets the license. Any code that needs Aspose will call into this method.

```
public class ConfigurationService
{
    private static bool isAsposePdfLicenseSet = false;

    public static void SetAsposePdfLicense()
    {
        if (isAsposePdfLicenseSet)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Set the license... (Moderately expensive - accesses the file system)

        isAsposePdfLicenseSet = true;
    }
}
```

I need to make sure the license is set before using my class, `PdfInspector`, but I only need to set it once, so I gave that class a static constructor:

```
static PdfInspector()
{
    ConfigurationService.SetAsposePdfLicense();
}
```

However, when I run Code Analysis in Visual Studio, it tells me that static constructors should be avoided. The alternative is to set the license in the constructor:

```
internal PdfInspector()
{
    ConfigurationService.SetAsposePdfLicense();
}
```

While this would be called every time the class is instantiated, the `SetAsposePdfLicense` would short circuit before doing any real logic. Bottom line, which implementation is preferable or is there an alternative that I haven't considered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what made me want to answer:

> ```
> // Set the license... (Moderately expensive - accesses the file system)
> ```

You do not want *any* constructor, static or not, to *do work* like this. A constructor that accesses the file system is screaming "**I CAN BLOW UP ANYTIME!**", and can throw file system -related exceptions. You don't want that in a constructor, even less a `static` one:

> *A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.*
>
> <sub>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx</sub>

Making your field `static` ensures that the *type* (not the *instance*) has the field value, and your logic ensures it's set only once *in the lifetime of your application*. If your application isn't starting any process (requirement is *once per process*, right?), it can probably work.

I don't like that you're *assuming* that your application will only ever call this method in the same process though - it's a fair assumption to make, but since the requirements say *once per process*, I think your code should account for `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id`, and call the `SetAsposePdfLicense()` method if the method wasn't called in the process your code is running in.

I'm thinking of a factory living in a *Singleton scope* (or just as a plain Singleton), that would maintain an `ICollection<int>` (a `HashSet<int>` would be ideal for this) where each item is a process ID for which `SetAsposePdfLicense` was called.

```
public class PdfInspectorFactory
{
    private readonly ICollection<int> _processes = new HashSet<int>();

    private void SetLicenseForCurrentProcess()
    {
        var currentProcessId = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
        if (_processes.Contains(currentProcessId))
        {
            return;
        }

        // set the license...

        _processes.Add(currentProcessId);
    }

    public PdfInspector Create()
    {
        SetLicenseForCurrentProcess();
        var inspector = new PdfInspector();

        // do whatever you need to do with your inspector before returning it

        return inspector;
    }
}
```

Then your client code can use this `PdfInspectorFactory` and call its `Create` method to get a `PdfInspector` without having to care about whether or not the license is set.

The client code will *not* call the factory method in its constructor, rather only when it needs it.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly PdfInspectorFactory _factory;

    public SomeClass(PdfInspectorFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        try
        {
            var inspector = _factory.Create();
            // here you go, now do what you need to do with your inspector...

        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            // todo: log or otherwise report exception
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The factory instance should only exist as a Singleton instance - if you're using an IoC container that is very easy to accomplish. Otherwise you need to implement the factory class itself, as a Singleton.

Comment: An `ISet` or an `IList`? Set or List? Set or List? <s>Million</s> 10 <s>dollar</s> reputation question.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg You're right, since the order of elements doesn't matter it's best to use an `ISet<int>` - although any `ICollection<int>` can work. `HashSet<int>` would probably be the most efficient implementation, edited. Thanks!

Comment: Wow, thanks. A lot to digest. I had a feeling that the correct answer was "neither". I've recently been learning about (and beginning to use) the factory and IoC patterns so this helps me to better understand their use. I could use some clarification on the distinction between a process and an application and static variable scope therein. Can an application consist of more than one process?

Comment: Yes. IIRC your program runs in a *process* that the .NET runtime puts in an *app domain*; your code is running on a *thread* that belongs to the *process*, and you can spawn new threads and new processes as you want - e.g. you may want to launch a command-line tool on a separate process, and do that on a background thread - everything still happens under the same *app domain* (you can also create a separate app domain with different privileges if you need to). But that whole part of my .NET knowledge is a bit rusty, you'll want to double-check all of it ;)

Comment: A `class` is a *definition* for a *type*. `static` members belong to the *type*, hence you don't need an *instance of the class* (i.e. an *object*) to use them. OOP mostly avoids `static` classes and members.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, I was curious about the process/ApplicationDomain/static member scope interaction, so I asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24287830/1812515) on [so]. The conclusion was that, without significant code gymnastics, static members are isolated to a single process. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use a `Nullable<bool>` or `bool?` :

```
private static bool? isAsposePdfLicenseSet = null;
private static bool IsAsposePdfLicenseSet
{
    get
    {
        if (isAsposePdfLicenseSet == null)
            ConfigurationService.SetAsposePdfLicense();

        return isAsposePdfLicenseSet.Value;
    }
}
```

The validation logic will be executed as soon as you start using `IsAsposePdfLicenseSet`. Assuming `SetAsposePdfLicense` will set the value for the backing field, it will only be initialized once.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what this buys me. I realize that my code in the question may not exactly show what I'm trying to do. I've edited the question for better clarity about how the code is written.

Comment: A Nullable boolean would not help at all. What purpose would `false` have in your case? The initial code has only two values: True and false. There's no need to add a third state.